# Clothing simulation instantly goes underneath mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, cloth-simulation, error, collision

I have a character here that I have modeled with a shirt on top of him.
[image]

On frame 16 without the cloth simulation, the clothes do not clip and are perfectly fine.
[image]

However, when I add the clothing simulation, the shirt glitches with the mesh and wants to go underneath the model.

[image]

By frame 30 it just gets terrible

[image]

My shirt geometry doesn't seem to be the problem, the model is scaled to 5 times its original size, and I recalculated the normals so I'm really not sure what to do.

[image]

For some extra information, I was following this Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg&t=390s
and all of my cloth and collision simulation settings are set to default.

Here is the project file Link:[image]

Comment: well...i suppose you are a very beginner at blender, because you made several mistakes here. First select both objects -> tab to edit mode -> Shift N to correct your face directions. You can see that they are wrong by clicking "face orientation" in viewport overlays. Right is "blue", red is wrong. And you should apply scale and rotation if you are simulating objects.

Comment: Yes this solved it thank you for the answer!